# Laravel check input in array

Tags: php, laravel

How can I check if my form input value exist in controller array?

## Code

```
$admins = User::role(['admin', 'superadmin'])->pluck('id'); // get array of admins id

if($request->input('user_id') == $admins) { // if user_id is include admins id...
 // do something
} else {
 // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `in_array` ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)) to check whether something exists in an array.

`if(in_array($request->input('user_id'), $admins)) { // if user_id is include admins id`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(in_array($request->input('user_id'), $admins)) { // if user_id is include admins id...
 // do something
} else {
 // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could as well perform it in a single query:

```
$user_admin = User::role(['admin', 'superadmin'])->find($request->input('user_id')); // returns null if not found or the $user if found

if($user_admin) { /
 // do something
} else {
 // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#available-methods) you can use their methods.

In this case you could use `contains()` method.

```php
$admins = User::role(['admin', 'superadmin'])->pluck('id'); //this return a collection

if($admins->contains($request->input('user_id'))) { // use the contains method of collection
 // do something
} else {
 // do something else
}
```

Comment: `->pluck()` returns a native array, not a collection. Using `->contains()` will throw an error.

Comment: @Joundill Hi! Could you tell me what error it gives you?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function contains() on array`

Comment: @Joundill Maybe I'm wrong but, the `pluck ()` function should return a collection not an array. You could use `collect ()` helper to make it a collection but if it is an array you have reason to use `in_array` as you have commented.
thanks for your help!